# Polars Row object to Dictionary

Tags: python, python-polars

I'm trying to iterate through the rows of a Polars DataFrame, where the iterator returns a dictionary of each row.

The [documentation](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.iter_rows.html#polars.DataFrame.iter_rows) indicates that iter_rows(named=True) is what I want.  However, I get an "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'iter_rows'" error when I try to use it.

iterrows(named=True) without the underscore does seem to mostly work, but it is returning a Polars Row object rather than a dictionary.  I can access the value using either integer indexes or dot notation with the column name, but it's not clear how I can get the column name / key.

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 2, 3],
    'b': [4, 5, 6]
})
for row in df.iterrows(named=True):
    print(type(row))
    print(row[0])
    print(row.a)
```

Is it possible to either get the column name / key values from the Row object or otherwise change it to a Python dictionary?

Comment: It seems that you should update polars.

Comment: yes, that seemed to be the issue. I went ahead and updated polars and got the result I was expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for `polars=0.16.11`:

```py
for row in df.iter_rows(named=True):
    print(row)
```

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 4}
{'a': 2, 'b': 5}
{'a': 3, 'b': 6}
```

Comment: They key was the correct version number